# Javascript: Stop running interval in background

Tags: firefox-addon

I am creating an extension for Firefox. This includes using `self.port`. Here's my code in `panel.js`:

```
self.port.on("showDlg", function(val) {
    document.getElementById('queen').onclick = function(){
        self.port.emit("song", 'queen');
    };
    document.getElementById('beatles').onclick = function(){
        self.port.emit("song", 'beatles');
    };
});
```

Here's the `content.js`:

```
self.port.on("song", function(val) {
    if (val.code = 'queen'){
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('show must go on');
        }, 1000);
    } else if (val.code == 'beatles'){
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('yesterday');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

It is all working, when I click `queen`, it prints me `show must go on` every 1 second. But when I click `beatles`, it still prints `show must go on` along with `yesterday`.

How can I stop previous interval? As far as I understand, it runs in the background, and every action is a new instance. If so, how can I stop previous instance?

Thanks.

Comment: use window.clearInterval

Comment: @SamvelAvanesov, no luck. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.port.on("song", function(val) {
    self.interval && clearInterval(self.interval);
    self.interval = null;
    if (val.code = 'queen'){
        self.interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('show must go on');
        }, 1000);
    } else if (val.code == 'beatles'){
        self.interval = setInterval(function () {
            console.log('yesterday');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, никак не работает (

Comment: @SeattleSam I have a feeling self is a frozen object. Define `interval` separately (above the snippet) and replace instances of `self.interval` with `interval`.